# Webhook for Firebase (FCM) Message expiry?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, webhooks, ttl

Is there any webhook (event) for message expiry
Ex:

- A message is sent to firebase
- It will be expired 28 days later (default TTL is 28 days)

Now I want the firebase to call my endpoint. Is this possible in Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into FCM to call back to your code when a message expires.